# How to set Backbone View attribute?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, attributes

I've got a [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) View which when I instantiate it, want to give it an attribute. I currently try to do this like so:

```
var myView = new MyView({'someId': 123});
```

and in MyView I do:

```
var Myview = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {'click .some-class': 'myMethod'},
    myMethod: function(e){
        console.log(this.someId);
    },
    // and some other things here..
});
```

When I click the some-class button I get a console message saying "undefined". I also tried it with the following:

```
myView.set({'someId': 123});
```

but that also doesn't work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it via the initialize options:

```
var Myview = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        this.someId = options.someId; 
    }, 
    events: {'click .some-class': 'myMethod'},
    myMethod: function(e){
        console.log(this.someId);
    },
    // and some other things here..
});
```